# Android: is reflection bad?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android, but I've done quite a bit of server side Java.

I was reading about Intents, and in particular about the difference between sending extra data (classes) via `Serializable` vs `Parcelable`. There seems to be a consensus that `Serializeable` has bad performance, and `Parcelable` is to be preferred. In some places I've seen it stated that `Serializeable` is bad because it uses reflection.

That leads to a couple of questions for me:

1. Is reflection in general considered bad? Should I avoid any library that relies heavily on reflection? For example, if I need JSON deserialization (from some web service) should I *not* be using Jackson or Gson? Is that org.json garbage really "best practice" in Android-land?
2. If I really should avoid reflection (and thus `Serializable`), is there any alternative to the ugly, boilerplate-heavy `Parcelable`? The Intents are all explicit, and I'm not broadcasting them outside the app. I guess I don't understand why in-process messaging can't just pass a reference to the object inside the Intent.

Comment: org.json also uses reflection. It's just more lightweight and feature-poor.

Comment: I would say it shouldn't be necessarily considered bad but you should avoid using it, if you can..

Comment: @dwnz the thing is, I can always avoid it, but typically the nicest libraries make use of it to avoid large amounts of boilerplate code. So there's a big trade off between concise and clear code, vs. performance concerns. Are those concerns real? Should I reject every major JSON parser and find one that doesn't use reflection?

Comment: @Kevin As you said, it is a trade off that it is up to you to choose which path to follow. EJK's answer is a good one in my opinion. If you are targeting low end mobile hardware then you should be, at least a bit, careful. If it is not, it should be fine as long as you don't over use it. And again "over use it" is a subjective thing here.

Answer (score 0):

RE question #2:

```
I guess I don't understand why in-process messaging can't just pass a reference to the object inside the Intent.
```

Parcelizing (or serializing) the object allows Android to re-create it when the containing activity is re-created itself.  Android controls the lifecycle of activities - and can at anytime destroy your activity, even if it is active/visible (e.g screen rotation, to reclaim memory to handle an incoming phone call, ...).  When Android re-creates your activity, it passes you an object called a Bundle that includes all your parcelized objects.  This allows you to restore the state of your activity, but note that these are not the original objects - they have been re-constitued from their parceled representations.

```
 is there any alternative...?
```

If you want to be able to properly re-create your activity, then parcelization and serialization are your choices.  I would not be so fast to rule out serialization however.  While in general it is less performant, in many cases, this will probably not be user-detectable.  Keep in mind that Android was designed at a time when mobile devices has significantly less processing power than they do today.  Thus performance optimizations like parcelability were likely more of a concern.

One alternative worth mentioning, which is probably even less performant would be to write the object to disk yourself.  Then in the intent, pass a pointer to the file (or the database record).  A variation on this would be to use Android SharePreferences to save the data.  I only mention this because passing large amounts of data in an Intent can sometimes fail.  There is no hard limit on the max object size, but many people, including me, have seen this failure.